# Пропорциональный ресайз изображения в ширину и в высоту

Tags: css3, изображения

Код, копия на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mySQ7/)

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.table__cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="table__cell">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/750x350" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Там использован стандартный прием с *display:block;* и *max-width:100%* для изображений:

```
img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Если увеличивать/уменьшать **ширину** контейнера, то изображение уменьшает/увеличивает свою ширину и одновременно пропорционально уменьшает/увеличивает свою высоту. Это очень крутая особенность изображений, много где выручает.

Как сделать так, чтобы при увеличении/уменьшении **высоты** контейнера, изображение вело себя подобно первому случаю: высота изображения становилась равна высоте контейнера и ширина изображения тоже пропорционально уменьшалась/увеличивалась? Как это сделать без Яваскрипта? (Как сделать с Яваскриптом я знаю.) Можно использовать самые новомодные CSS3 штуки.

Answer (score 5):

В общем, как оказалось, достаточно всего одного правила и блочный контейнер вокруг, чтобы изображение скейлилось и по высоте — ***max-height:100%***:

```
img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

Вот готовенький [фиддл](http://jsfiddle.net/fPGJv/). (Естественно, ресайзить нужно жсфиддловский фрейм (ака контейнер)).

Опытным путем было выяснено, что такой ресазй возможен только внутри блочных элементов (например, ***body***). В элементах с ***display:table*** и ***display:table-cell*** изображение ресайзится только в ширину, а с ***display:flex*** не ресайзится вообще никак.

Придется пропорционально ресайзить Яваскриптом.

Answer (score 4):

Если я правильно понял, то вам надо изменять размер изображения при изменении размеров окна браузера **по высоте**.

В этом случае, средствами CSS это не получится сделать так же, как и с шириной, по той причине, что высота как бы не имеет предела, а значит нет возможности установить высоту относительно окна браузера в процентном соотношении.

В данной ситуации я пока вижу только один выход - это медиа-запросы ([@media](http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media)). Плавного изменения изображения тут ждать не приходиться, хотя некоторую [имитацию, всё же сделать можно](http://jsfiddle.net/mySQ7/4/):

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.table__cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 500px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-duration: 2s;
}
img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
@media (max-height: 600px) {
    .table__cell {
        -moz-transform:  scale(0.7);
        -ms-transform:  scale(0.7);
        -webkit-transform:  scale(0.7);
        -o-transform:  scale(0.7);
        transform:  scale(0.7);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="table__cell">
        <img src="http://www.nn.ru/data/forum/images/2009-12/17931702-putin-obyavil-.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

В примере, изменяйте фрейм.

[image]